# Sonar build fails with NullPointerException

Tags: java, hudson, jenkins, sonarqube

I have set up a sonar target in jenkins.  It used to work, but started throwing the following exception a few days ago.

I can't see what is wrong.  The code compiles locally, anbd passes in the non-Sonar target build.

Any ideas??

```
[INFO] Instrumentation was successful.
[INFO] NOT adding cobertura ser file to attached artifacts list.
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Compiling 14 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/4Life-SONAR/4lifestyle/target/test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_20). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$MethodSymbol.params(Symbol.java:1212)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.attachParameterAnnotations(ClassReader.java:1125)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readMemberAttr(ClassReader.java:885)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readMemberAttrs(ClassReader.java:1041)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1504)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:1600)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClassFile(ClassReader.java:1672)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.fillIn(ClassReader.java:1859)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.complete(ClassReader.java:1791)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:400)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:782)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.loadClass(ClassReader.java:1965)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.loadClass(Resolve.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdentInPackage(Resolve.java:1021)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.selectSym(Attr.java:1969)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:1883)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1651)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:372)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:402)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.attribImportType(MemberEnter.java:693)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitImport(MemberEnter.java:557)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport.accept(JCTree.java:507)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:400)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:412)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitTopLevel(MemberEnter.java:524)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:454)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:400)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.complete(MemberEnter.java:831)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:400)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:782)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:481)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:459)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:895)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:795)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:380)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:306)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:297)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:554)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:605)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.TestCompilerMojo.execute(TestCompilerMojo.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.forkProjectLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1205)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.forkLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1038)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:643)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.sonar.maven2.Maven2PluginExecutor.execute(Maven2PluginExecutor.java:65)
    at org.sonar.maven2.Maven2PluginExecutor.execute(Maven2PluginExecutor.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.SensorsExecutor.executeMavenPlugin(SensorsExecutor.java:69)
    at org.sonar.batch.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:55)
    at org.sonar.batch.ProjectBatch.execute(ProjectBatch.java:53)
    at org.sonar.batch.AggregatorBatch.analyzeProject(AggregatorBatch.java:109)
    at org.sonar.batch.AggregatorBatch.analyzeProject(AggregatorBatch.java:106)
    at org.sonar.batch.AggregatorBatch.analyzeProjects(AggregatorBatch.java:101)
    at org.sonar.batch.AggregatorBatch.execute(AggregatorBatch.java:85)
    at org.sonar.maven2.BatchMojo.executeBatch(BatchMojo.java:149)
    at org.sonar.maven2.BatchMojo.execute(BatchMojo.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:98)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:75)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)

[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar
```

Comment: It looks like a bug in the java compiler. It works locally with exactly the same version of javac? It may be triggered by something Sonar's doing to instrument the build. Can you upgrade the jdk on your CI server?

Comment: Thanks - upgrading to jdk 1.7 fixed it.  Add as an answer if you want the answer points!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have encountered this Java bug:

> [Bug 6889255 - javac MethodSymbol throws NPE if ClassReader does not read parameter names correctly](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6889255)

There are other incarnations too; e.g.

> Netbeans issue [180191](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=180191)

The fix is to upgrade your JDK to a more recent build.

Comment: I'm using the latest java 6 JDK for Linux, still there.

Comment: @JohnHinnegan - try Java 7.  If that doesn't work perhaps you have encountered a different (new?) bug.